# Agrupación y filtro por percentil con pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, percentil, filtro

Me gustaría agrupar un conjunto de datos por rangos de coordenadas (histograma) y filtrar aquellos valores que queden por encimar del percentil p = 0.97 (datos fuera de las zonas marcadas en verde)

[image: filtro]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu, sigma = 0, 0.2
x = np.abs(np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000))
y = np.abs(np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000))
p_id = np.linspace(1,1000,1000)

x_bins = np.linspace(0,1,11) # especificados por usuario


data =  pd.DataFrame({'x': x,
                     'y': y},
                    index=p_id)
data.plot.scatter(x='x',y='y')
plt.show()
```

[image: Datos]

De momento, me gusta la idea de mantener la información de grupos en cada fila.

```
data['x_groups'] = pd.cut(data['x'], bins=x_bins, include_lowest=False )
data = data.sort_values('x_groups')
ydata_xgrouped = data.groupby('x_groups')['y']
ydata_xgrouped.describe()
```

[image: descripción]

De esta forma puedo calcular el percentil (o cuantil) que me gustaría también incorporar a la tabla.

```
p_top_groups = ydata_xgrouped.quantile(0.97)


data.plot.scatter(x='x',y='y')
plt.bar(x_bins[1:]-0.05, p_top_groups.values, width=0.1,
        align='center', alpha=0.5, color='green')

plt.show()
```

Y por último filtrar los datos quedándome solo con los que aparecen en el rango deseado 0>=p <= 0.97  (ver imagen inicial)

```
 # data_clean = data._.filter._(y.p ... ) ??
```

Estoy seguro de que se puede realizar esta operación en menos líneas. Por ejemplo, he visto que se puede aplicar el método transform después de un groupby. Sin embargo, estoy teniendo problemas con esta funcionalidad.

**Actualización**: si el DataFrame tiene un NaN (original o incorporado por groupby) la operación transform devolverá el siguiente error.

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 999 elements, new values have 1000 elements
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efectivamente, podrías usar transform para obtener aquellos puntos que están por debajo del percentil 97 de su grupo del siguiente modo:

```
cond = ydata_xgrouped.transform(lambda df: df < df.quantile(0.97))
cond.head()
```

Esto devuelve una serie con el mismo índice que `data` de tal manera que lo puedes utilizar para filtrar los puntos que están por debajo del percentil 97 de su grupo:

```
data[cond == True]
```

Se pueden comprobar los resultados con:

```
ax = data.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y')
data[cond == True].plot.scatter(x='x', y='y', edgecolors='r', facecolors='none', ax=ax)
plt.bar(x_bins[1:]-0.05, p_top_groups.values, width=0.1, align='center', alpha=0.3, color='green')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias. He editado la pregunta para indicar el origen de los problemas con esta funcionalidad. Si hay NaN la operación devuelve un error: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#na-and-nat-group-handling